# Расчет выстрела ИИ

Tags: python, python-3.x

есть игра морской бой, дело в том что я хотел бы научить ии не просто по тупому бить в рандомные места на карте, а если он попал в один из кораблей то чтобы он бил рядом с попавшей точкой до тех пор пока не потопит корабль, с помощью какой формулы можно научить его это просчитывать? Вот как выглядят выстрелы и их обработка:

```
def try_attack(self, hit_point):
    for i, p in enumerate(self.points):
        if p == hit_point:
            if p.was_hit:
                return False, SHOT_ALREADY_MADE
            p.was_hit = True
            self.points[i] = p
            if self.check_dead():
                return True, SHOT_DRAWN_SHIP
            return True, SHOT_SHIP_WAS_HIT
    return False, None

@staticmethod
def is_shot_was_made(hit_point, team):
    shot = team.field_of_shots[hit_point.x + hit_point.y * MAP_SIZE]
    return shot != Shots.NONE

@staticmethod
def is_shot_correct(hit_point, team):
    for i in range(hit_point.y - 1, hit_point.y + 2):
        for j in range(hit_point.x - 1, hit_point.x + 2):
            p = _Point.normalize_point(_Point(j, i, hit_point.value, False))
            if team.field_of_shots[p.x + p.y * MAP_SIZE] == Shots.DRAWN:
                return False
    return True

def process_shot(self, hit_point, team, opponent):
    if self.is_shot_was_made(hit_point, opponent):
        return SHOT_ALREADY_MADE, None
    for rank in shipRanks:
        for ship in opponent.ships[rank]:
            was_hit, msg = ship.try_attack(hit_point)
            if was_hit:
                opponent.field_of_shots[hit_point.x + hit_point.y * MAP_SIZE] = \
                    Shots.DRAWN if msg == SHOT_DRAWN_SHIP else Shots.HIT
                self.shot_was_made(was_hit, team)
            if msg:
                return msg, ship
    opponent.field_of_shots[hit_point.x + hit_point.y * MAP_SIZE] = Shots.MISSED
    return None, None
```

Comment: Проверять 4 варианта от клетки, в которую попал?

Comment: Ещё надо проверять оставшиеся клетки куда может поместиться корабль. Начальную пробивку делать так чтоб попасть по самым большим

Answer (score 1, accepted):

кодом не помогу, но сам подход у тебя выполнен слегка неправильно.

1. Тут ненужна формула, достаточно правильно реализовать код
2. Для это задачи лучше использовать ООП, вместо исключительно функций в связке с декораторами
3. Как только бот попал в корабль, он выбирает одну из 4-х случайных клеток возле выстрела, если промахнулся, тогда возвращаем функцию, которая отвечала за выбор 4-х случайных попаданий и убираем, ту позицию в которую мы выстрелили, но промахнулись и после у нас остаётся выбор из 3-х клеток, а если выстрел попал, тогда (тут идёт чистая математика) просто берём значения (x, y) по координатам и вычисляем места попадания, после их вычисления, бот будет бить по кораблю до того момента, пока не потопит корабль
4. После потопления корабля сразу блокируй все прилежащие клетки к кораблю по причине того, что по правилам игры они не могут находиться впритык друг к другу